# What is the easiest way to get --ours and --theirs version of a file without overwriting working (checked out) version?

Tags: git

Basically all I want is to `git checkout --ours A` to `/tmp/A.ours` and `git checkout --theirs /tmp/A.theirs` without changing the current A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are in the middle of a merge conflict? In that case:

```
git show :2:A > /tmp/A.ours
git show :3:A > /tmp/A.theirs
```

Comment: See the help for specifying revisions syntax, specifically [the stage-number syntax being used here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltngtltpathgtemegem0READMEememREADMEem).

Comment: Nice, didn't know about this syntax. Thanks!